# javascript event fire only one

Tags: javascript, css

I am having a problem with the code below.
The code should handle the slider and changes between them when the `img` is 
clicked, it works only once.

when I changed the onClick event to

```
    document.getElementById("left").onclick = function(){
        console.log("0");
    }
```

It worked fine, but when I reverted, it doesn't change the slider more than once

snippet:

```js
var index = 0;

document.getElementById("left").onclick = function(){
  console.log("0");
}

document.getElementById("left").onclick = function(){
  var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");
  slider[index].style.display = "none";
  if(index == 0){ index = slider.length;}
  slider[--index].style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("right").onclick = function(){
  var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");
  slider[index].style.display = "none";
  if(index >= slider.length){ index = 0;}
  slider[++index].style.display = "block";
};
```

```html
<div class="slider" style="display: block">
  <div id = "left"><img src="Images/arrow-left.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="text">
    <h2>welcome to the <span>classic</span></h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum is a name for a common type of placeholder text. Also known as filler or dummy text, this is simply copy that serves to fill a space</p>
  </div>
  <div id = "right"><img src="Images/arrow-right.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you check the console in your browser, it might provide you with some guidance. For example, I get an error: `(index):36 Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.document.getElementById.onclick ((index):36)`

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to add it.

Comment: it is var index = 0;

Comment: I have suggested an edit to present your code as snippet, so the community can help you easier.

Comment: left arrow and right arrow button should be outside the slider because as your slider moves the buttons change to which means events listener are added to only one Element with ID

Answer (score 2):

thanks guys, the problem was that I gave multiple div the same ID which made the onclick event only fire once (with the first div only)